# Handling DBNull and null in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, mysql, database, null, dbnull

What is the best way of rewriting these (erroneous) lines?

> bool? result = dr["result"] == DBNull.Value ? null : Convert.ToInt32(dr["result"]);

...and...

> dr["result"] = result ?? DBNull.Value;

Both do not compile.

I am using the MySql connector and it doesn't let me set, for example, `dr["result"] = null;` which is what I first tried.

Is there an more suitable .NET data type for representing a MySql nullable `tinyint(1)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
     dr["Hello"] = (object)result ?? DBNull.Value;
     bool? result = dr["result"] == DBNull.Value ? null : (bool?)(Convert.ToInt32(dr["result"]) != 0);
```

The reason your suggestion does not compile is that both alternatives of the ternary operator `?:` must have the same type. `DBNull.Value` obviously is not the same type as a `bool?`. Casting the `bool?` to an `object` however makes them both the same type. Similar rules apply on the second row.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using a stored procedure or SQL queries then you can use `ISNULL()` function of SQL to handle NULL...